# Getting All Same IDs with Java Script

Tags: javascript, menu

The java script only get the first id. The 2nd id ignores the code. Are there anyway to make both IDs using the same java script ?

Add Item
        List Items

```
<div id="add_item" class="tabcontent">
<div id="subcatchooser"></div>   

<div id="list_item" class="tabcontent">

<div id="subcatchooser"></div>
```

Java Script here

```
function showsubcat(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("subcatchooser").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("subcatchooser").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?action=showsubcat&parent_id=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: That's how it should work, id's are supposed to be unique. It's strictly against the HTML markup specification if they are not. Attempting to get an id will return the first one found in the DOM. Use classes instead.

Comment: if you can't (for whatever reason) have unique ID's - use `document.querySelectorAll('#subcatchooser')` - having said that, unique ID's are a cornerstone of valid HTML - so, don't do this

Comment: Use classes instead of id's. Then use `document.getElementsByClassName`. **EDIT:** Julia Nething already took my spotlight, so just forget I ever said anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the main difference between classes and IDs. Classes are designed to be used multiple times, while IDs are designed to be unique. So you can change the divs to look like this:

```
<div class="subcatchooser"></div>
```

And then change the JavaScript to look like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("subcatchooser");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: [*getElementsByClassName*](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) returns a live [*HTMLCollection*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection) which doesn't have an *innerHTML* property. :-)

Comment: Thanks @RobG! My apologies, fixing now